# How to detect memory leak in the linux kernel 2.6.29

Tags: linux-kernel, memory-leak

Is there a way to find out if Linux kernel is leaking memory by running some commands? I am almost positive that the linux kernel is leaking memory. However, the top and free -k do not reveal much. Is there a way that I can look at how much memory kernel has allocated and hopefully some kind of a memory map too?
Thanks for any inputs

Comment: Your question is pretty specific - you might get a more useful response if you describe the behaviour that you're seeing and say why you think there might be a kernel memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at /proc/meminfo:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo
```

The resulting fields are described in the [kernel documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt).

If you see `Slab` or `KernelStack` growing over time then maybe you're on to something. However, if the big consumers are `AnonPages`, `Mapped` and `Shmem` then it's a userspace issue not a kernel issue.